# How do I configure g-simple so it does not use G81 code?

Tags: machining, computer-aided-design, cnc, drilling

I have a CNC that does not understand the G81 code for drilling. G-Simple looks to be configurable but I am finding it difficult to find information on it. It looks to have a "USE" command with a "G81" parameter but no idea how to make it not use this command and just drill a hole by constructing the movements itself. Just a simple CNC so not too bothered about the timing etc.

Comment: Does your post processor have settings? Can you disable "canned cycles"?  Sometimes you can edit the drilling output and you can customize the output to get what you want. I don't know G-Simple.

Comment: G-simple is producing the g-code that I am then sending to the cnc. There is no intermediate file format. I think that is what you are implying.